# ZF2 | Routing post data using Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Method

Tags: url-routing, zend-framework2

## Routing post data in ZF2

I have tried to set up a routing in zf2 where all post data of the route `/connection/add` is routing to a separate method using this yaml configurations:

```
router:
  routes:
    home:
      type: literal
      options:
        route: '/'
        defaults:
          controller: Admin\Dashboard
          action:     index

    connection:
      type: literal
      options:
        route: '/connection'
        defaults:
          controller: Admin\Connection
          action:     list

      may_terminate: true
      child_routes:
        add:
          type: literal
          options:
            route: '/add'
            defaults:
              action: add

          may_terminate: true
          child_routes:
            post:
              type: method
              options:
                verb: post
                defaults:
                  action: test
```

Everything in the above example works just fine, except the deepest child `post` that is using the type of [Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Method](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-method)

### Expected output:

When one is submitting post data to the rout `/connection/add`, that person will be routed to the `test` action.

### Actual output:

The last child in the above routing is ignored and the `add` action is still invoked upon dispatching post data sent from a form.

### Question:

- What am I missing?
- Is there a way to have this kind of routing in my application?
- If so, how could the configuration look?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It actually is possible, it just requires a little more explicit configuration.

The reason your example wasn't working is because the router matched your 'add' route successfully and simply returned there without looking ahead. You have to tell it that it can't terminate there by setting 'may_terminate' to false and explicitly defining all methods you want to deal with in the child_routes.

```
    add:
        type: Literal
        options:
            route: '/add'
            defaults:
                action: add
        may_terminate: false
        child_routes:
            post:
                type: method
                options:
                    verb: post
                    defaults:
                        action: test
            everythingelse:
                type: method
                options:
                    verb: 'get,head,put,delete'
                    defaults:
                        action: add
```

Remember, the key is to set 'may_terminate' to false so the router doesn't return a match too early.

Comment: Use $this->url ('add/everythingelese') in your view to assemble the url if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you've got it as a child of the add route, maybe try adding it on the same level rather than as a child?

```
 child_routes:
    add:
      type: literal
      options:
        route: '/add'
        defaults:
          action: add
      may_terminate: true
    post:
      type: method
      options:
        verb: post
        defaults:
          action: test
      may_terminate: true
```

Make it so it's not a child of the 'add' route, rather a sibling.

Comment: Wouldn't this match all post data? I'm only looking to rout the post data that matches the rout: '/add'